# loop on :nth-child with a delay for (1n+0)

Tags: jquery, sass, css-selectors

1) What is the better method to choose? compiled CSS or jQuery  (presumed jQuery)

2) How would I correctly transfer the SASS to jQuery? (.shape is the class event is looping through)

SASS

```
$elements: 120;
$base-color: gray;

@for $i from 0 to $elements {
.shape:nth-child(#{$i}) {
-webkit-animation-delay:-$i * 0.1s;
-moz-animation-delay:-$i * 0.1s;
animation-delay:-$i * 0.1s;
border-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
z-index:$i;
}
}
```

jQuery

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 120; i++) {
    $(".shape :nth-child(1n+0)").delay(100);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Why would you use scripts to do styling? The appropiate way is to use CSS.
2. Anyway if you want/need to do that in jQuery would be:

   ```
   for (var i = 1; i <= 120; i++) {
     $(".shape :nth-child(1n+"+i+")").css('animation-delay', (i*0.1)+'s');
   }
   ```